# PHP splitting a string into 2 values

Tags: php, string, variables, split, explode

hello I have a string the shows a users height like this,

> 6' 3"

I wanting to spilt this string into two values FEET and INCHES so I am left with something similar too,

`$feet = "6'";

$inches = "3"/"`

I so far have tried to do the following, to no avail,

`split("[']", $height)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$height = "6' 3\"";
list($feet, $inches) = explode(" ", $height);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/9WbAl1dn

Comment: +1 I love answers with demos!  It takes 10 seconds and really makes it clear what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Split ist the Javascript function for this. You are looking for [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)().

```
$array = explode(" ", $height)
```

You can combine it with [list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)() to split the array into varialbes:

```
list($feet, $inches) = explode(" ", $height)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PHP explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the numeric values of feet and inches:

```
$parts = explode("' ", trim($height, '"'));
$feet = $parts[0];
$inches = $parts[1];
```

Combined with [Neal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228798/244826):

```
$height = "6' 3\"";
list($feet, $inches) = explode("' ", trim($height, '"'));
```

Comment: hmmmm that seems a bit complicated for no reason.

Comment: @Neal - Which part seems to be without reason?

Comment: I listed the reason. It's to get *only the numeric values*.

Comment: Sorry for trying to add value ;-)